# Tradução da medalha "Sobreano"

Tags: bug, status-pronto, localização

Na lista referente ao nome das medalhas a tradução do nome da medalha Sobreano nao deveria ser Soberano ?

Comment: @Gabe está pronto mas qual foi a tradução escolhida?

Comment: @JorgeB. Botei um comentário na resposta do Bacco

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Soberano **não** é a tradução correta.

Provavelmente precisa ser melhor traduzida, mas não para nenhuma dessas duas coisas. A original é "Yearling", e "Sobre-ano" foi uma tradução infeliz (mas não foi erro de digitação).

Provavelmente seria algo na linha de "aniversariante", mas pode ser melhor pensado. Seria legal a comunidade dar sugestões.

Comment: Traduzido como aniversariante. É a mais votada e certamente passa a mensagem correta.

Answer (score 3):

Dando prosseguimento ao gancho deixado na resposta do @Bacco de deixar sugestões, que tal chamar esta medalha de *"Um ano de casa"* ou *"Um ano de trabalho"*?